# ASP.Net MVC application login session handling with Web Api services

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I am working on application whose details are as follows:

1. Its 3 tier architecture. Web Tier (ASP.Net MVC) -- Service Tier (ASP.Net WebApi 2) -- Database Tier(MS SQL 2014).
2. Application will also have native mobile apps as clients which will consume Service tier.
3. Service Tier (Web API) uses individual username/password in conjunction with OAuth for authentication and authorization.
4. User details are stored using ASP. Net Identity system. ASP. Net Identity database tables are in same database as that of application database.
5. There will be no direct calls from clients i.e. web or mobile apps to database and every request has to go via service layer.
6. Users of web client and mobile apps will be authenticated against asp.net identity database which is part of application database.

I have partially implemented above architecture however facing one challenge i.e. once user is authenticated, OAuth token will be issued from service layer which will be valid for one day. But how and where should I securely store this token in Web Client (ASP.Net MVC app) so that user needs to login only once in day and not for every single request that it makes.
One option I can think of is once user is authenticated and token is received in web client then store it in in-memory session storage and use it for further requests. However down side of this is, it will reduce scalability of application and will require sticky sessions in load balanced environment.
Is there any better way I can handle this situation? Also want to validate above architecture if its correct architecture?

Comment: You can't store at client side like cookie, so better you store it at session. And for scalability or in case of load balanced environment you can store session to DB side.

Comment: For your web application you can also store it into authentication cookie which is encrypted.

Comment: @RuchirShah Yes you can store it in a cookie and this is preferred over session as it will persist when the browser has closed and the user revisits the site. You could use the Forms Authentication cookie seen as though you're already using the ASP.NET Membership Provider.

Comment: Your Web API could return the token as response cookie. The client would then automatically send this cookie value in all subsequent request (request cookie). Use an authorization filter for your related logic - http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters